# Annotation supported by SP2010?

Tags: document-converter

Just wanted to verify if annotation on documents (word, pdf or any other document type) is supported by Sharepoint 2010, OOTB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the Notes and Tags feature?

The Notes and Tags feature is one of the social features you can use that will let you add notes and tags on list items and documents on SharePoint.  See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff608137.aspx.

Comment: Thanks John. I think I was looking for the "Note Board" feature that allows me to stick my comments into the document or the page.